# Relational mysql Table search without primary key in yii (calling a non integer field)

Tags: mysql, yii

### Table One:

```
ar_codes
----------
ar_id (primary key),
act_id,
ar_code,
status
```

### Table Two:

```
act_req_recv
----------
rcv_id (primary key),
act_id,
rcv_person,
status
```

Now I need to find the `ar_code`field value from **ar_codes** table for the `rcv_person` field of **act_req_recv** table. Both of the table has one common field which is `act_id` and is not a primary key for both of the table.

Now I can find it by normal mysql scriptlike bellow command, where $actId is carrying the value. How can I find this value in Yii?

```
SELECT ar_code FROM ar_codes WHERE act_id=$actId
```

I tried to find that with a function call from model. But as the field is not PK so the result is not coming.

```
public static function getAR_code($actId) {
    $ActCode = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('ar_code')
            ->from('{{ar_codes}}')
            ->where('act_id=' . (int) $actId)
            ->queryAll();
    return $ActCode;
}
```

Getting this error when the function run:

> [error] [php] Array to string conversion
>   (D:\Xampp\htdocs\framework\yii1.1.19\zii\widgets\CDetailView.php:240)

The cDetail View Code is:

```
array(
    'name' => 'actId',
    'type'=> 'raw',
    'value' => ActivityRecord::getAR_code($model->actId), 
    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => "text-align:left;"),
),
```

Comment: Can you show your view with `CDetailView`? Query looks OK, probably you're using result in a wrong way.

Comment: cDetailview code has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryAll()` returns array of rows, so it is actually array of arrays. Something like:

```
[
    ['ar_code' => 123],
]
```

If you want to query single value (for example `123`), you should use [`queryScalar()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryScalar-detail) - it will return value from first column of first row:

```
public static function getAR_code($actId) {
    return Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('ar_code')
            ->from('{{ar_codes}}')
            ->where('act_id=' . (int) $actId)
            ->queryScalar();
}
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks @rob006. The issue has been solved.

Comment: I am new at Stackoverflow and was not able to find the Accept button. Now I find that the Tick Mark, is it okay?